# How to Change Font Label in Dropdown in CKEditor on headings?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor, editor

In **CKEditor** when i change styles from **Normal** to **H1, H2 or H3** the font label in drop down isn't changing!

I want to change the font label when user change styles of Headings automatically. How can i do it?

[image]

**Content.css**

```
h1
{
    font-size: 28px !important;
}
h2
{
    font-size: 24px !important;
}
h3
{
    font-size: 22px !important;
}
h4
{
    font-size: 20px !important;
}
h5
{
    font-size: 18px !important;
}
```

The font label which is highlighted should change according to the defined css! I tried the above by adding the css in **contents.css** but it isn't working!

Comment: Add the HTML, we just don't know the elements that you are using, so we can't know where to change to help you

Comment: CKEditor just targets by name or id! I think that's not necessary to add! If someone is developer he/she knows it!

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 separate things.

First: defining style in such way will only apply for visual aspect of text in CKEditor. It won't change automatically for font-size.

Second: Font size are applied with span elements. You can have `h1` element with different sizes selected with this button. To manipulate available options for font size you can use [`fontSize_sizes`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-fontSize_sizes), but it won't detect them automatically from h1 stylesheet.

Please take a look in details how manage styles in CKEditor: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_howtos_styles